# Python, httplib2, Unexpected error: socket.error

Tags: python, sockets, httplib2

Using python 2.4.3 I'm trying to make a HTTP server which:  (1)gets a message with 'POST', (2) makes an answer message, (3) send the answer message back to sender.

Step (1) and (2) go well, Step 3 fails.... sometimes. It looks like there is some threading issue with the used httplib2.Http() thing. 
The output when it fails is:

> ```
> Unexpected error: socket.error
> 10.96.5.127 - - [26/May/2014 07:55:39] code 500, message Error processing in do_POST
> 10.96.5.127 - - [26/May/2014 07:55:39] "POST /exchange/PERFOR HTTP/1.1" 500 -
> ```

Here is my code (import are not shown) :

```
class PostHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_POST(self):
        try:
            # (1) Message from sender is received by server : OK
            content_len = int(self.headers.getheader('content-length'))
            msg = self.rfile.read(content_len)
            self.send_response(200)
            self.end_headers()
            # (2) Received message is used to make the 'smsg' message to be send back.
            # This goes OK so I don't need to show the code.
            # (3) Now 'smsg' shoud be send back to sender
            headers = {"Content-type" : "text/xml" , "Accept": "text/xml" , "User-Agent" :  "haboob/5.9.0.0.4 build-4857" , "SOAPAction": "\"ebXML\"" }
            url = 'http://mynode.local:4080/destination'
            http = httplib2.Http()
            response, content = http.request(url, method="POST", headers=headers, body=smsg)
        except :
            print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
            self.send_error(500,'Error processing in do_POST')
        return

class ThreadedHTTPServer(ThreadingMixIn, HTTPServer):
    """Handle requests in a separate thread."""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        port=4080
        server = ThreadedHTTPServer(('',port), PostHandler) 
        server.request_queue_size=60
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print ('^C received, shutting down server')
        server.socket.close()
```

Any help will be very welcome!

Comment: Your codes have mixed whitespace and tabs as indent. That's harmful in Python. Only use either one of them

Comment: You are right. Thank you . However since the script sometimes works this cannot be my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a way to solve this.
I added after (1) the following line:

`time.sleep(0.25)`

This way the sockets opened to receive a message gets the time to close.